# How do I plot data from a regrouped dataframe in python (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe which I have regrouped from a large dataset (this is just a sample).

How do I plot the data in a way that on the x axis you would have the time (starting May 2019) and the y axis would show the individual actvities with their monthly duration?

```html
date_year   date_month  activity    duration
2019                     5  activity 1  23
                                activity 2  34
                                activity 3  12
                                activity 4  45
                                activity 5  12
                                activity 6  32
                                activity 7  43
                                activity 8  12
2019    6                   activity 1  11
                                activity 2  34
                                activity 3  12
                                activity 4  45
                                activity 5  78
                                activity 6  32
                                activity 7  43
                                activity 8  12
2019    7                   activity 1  34
                                activity 2  34
                                activity 3  12
                                activity 4  22
                                activity 5  78
                                activity 6  32
                                activity 7  55
                                activity 8  99
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
df = df1.reset_index().convert_dtypes()
df['date'] = df['date_year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['date_month'].astype(str)
df[['date', 'activity', 'duration']].set_index(
    ['date', 'activity']).unstack(-1).plot(kind='bar')
```

OUTPUT:

[image]